# Is there a lightweight 3D Mesh Viewer library or framework in C++ besides Pangolin?

Tags: mesh, 3d-slam

I'm working with SLAM in C++ and used for this the good old pangolin viewer, but now I want to create a triangulated mesh in this viewer. Before I start with my programming, I thought I will do some research, if there are better viewers who can render meshes (if possible in realtime). So, I found easy3D which is compared to the PangolinViewer pretty new. Before I spend to much time into it, I thought someone here could have some experience in this field and would like to share it with me.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Given the context of SLAM/robotics, the first thing that comes into mind is [Gazebo Sim](https://gazebosim.org/home).

Gazebo Sim (i.e. 'new' Gazebo, as opposed to [Gazebo Classic](https://classic.gazebosim.org/)) is a full-fledged simulator, but is implemented as multiple libraries that can also be used stand-alone.

[`gz-rendering`](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-rendering/tree/gz-rendering8) is its rendering library. There is a [mesh viewer example](https://gazebosim.org/api/rendering/8/mesh_viewer.html) (see the corresponding code [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-rendering/tree/gz-rendering8/examples/mesh_viewer)).

The benefit of using `gz-rendering` is that, if you'd decide at some point to use Gazebo Sim for simulation, you already have a deep understanding of (one of) its core libraries, so can easily tweak your simulation to your needs.

The drawback is that there is limited documentation, so depending on what you try to achive, it is not always trivial.